# Copy constructor works faster on copying std::vector<int64_t> than std::copy

Tags: c++, performance, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <string.h>

std::vector<int64_t> vec;
static const int64_t N = 100000000;
static const int64_t M = N - 1;

void func1() {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::vector<int64_t> dst;
    dst.resize(M);
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + M, dst.begin());
}

void func2() {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::vector<int64_t> dst;
    dst.resize(M);
    memcpy(&dst[0], &vec[0], M * sizeof(int64_t));
}
void func3() {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::vector<int64_t> dst(vec);
    dst.resize(M);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    vec.resize(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        vec[i] = i;
    }

    auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    if (argc == 1) {
        func1();
    } else if (argc == 2) {
        func2();
    } else {
        func3();
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time difference = "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds> \
        (end - begin).count()
        << "[µs]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I thought std::copy might be slightly faster than copy constructor, as `func1() vs func3()`.

But it turned out that `func3()` had best performance. Why?

func3
Time difference = 658007[µs]

func2
Time difference = 823092[µs]

func1
Time difference = 838711[µs]

I've also tested std::vector, `func1` faster than `func3`. `SomeStruct` includes `std::string` and

```
struct A {
    A(int64_t a) : A_(a) {}
    int64_t a_;
};
```

compile command: g++ test.cpp -std=c++11
I ran several times and the results seem the same.

Comment: "I thought std::copy might be slightly faster than copy constructor" - why?

Comment: `std::copy` is a generic function for copying. Copy-constructor of a given class, knows the internals of said class, and knows the most efficient way to copy the data in those internals, that generic function cannot know.

Comment: You need to create iterators for std::copy.

Comment: What compiler? What compile options? How many times did you run it and how stable were the results?

Comment: To test performance of `std::copy()` without using `resize()`, you can use this: `std::vector<int64_t> dst; dst.reserve(M); std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + M, std::back_inserter(dst));`

Comment: The posted timings do not mean anything until we see how you compiled your application.  If you're timing a "debug" or unoptimized build, the timings are meaningless.

Comment: [Quick bench's timing](http://quick-bench.com/KMXsMnOk321ybMDSdoNTpqFW9t0).

Comment: Yeah, so you should generally be using `-O3` to benchmark (or whatever your standard release level is). Running something "several times" and things "seeming" the same is also a worry - I'd generally run something hundreds of times and look at the mean, variance, discard outliers etc. etc. Even if you don't use it, you can see the lengths [gbench](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/master/README.md) goes to, to get good measurements.

Answer (score 4):

Copy constructor can copy content of a source vector directly into newly allocated uninitialized memory, especially if contained type is primitive type or POD. Vector implementations are often optimized for this. And on the other hand, call to `resize()` has to fill newly allocated space with default value (or value that you have specified to `resize()`), because vector elements cannot be uninitialized. This obviously takes additional time. That's why `func1()` and `func(2)` are slower.

Comment: With as-if rule, compiler might generate the same code for all (as `capacity` might differ, it will probably not be the same, but idea is here).